# Trusting a shared mysql server exposed on the internet

Tags: mysql, security, dbaas

I have the possibility to use a **shared mysql server** offered by a reliable Italian cloud provider (Aruba). The service satisfies my performance needs and would notably simplify my infrastructure.

My concern is that this shared mysql service (DBaaS) is only offered with **public ip address** exposed on the internet, authentication with userid and password and SSL connection.

The data that I would move to this server are reservations and accounting for a certain number of hotels. It's definitely critical and confidential data and a data breach would be definitely a disaster.

Till now, my infrastructure is based on a firewall that only exposes the web server, while the database server is a custom VM connected through a virtual switch and not visible on the internet.

How bigger is the danger of such an infrastructure (DBaaS with public ip address) compared to my actual setup with a private VM running mysql on an internal IP address?

**PROS:** security, updates and firewalling would be managed by the cloud provider in a more consistent and persistent way

**CONS:** exposure on the internet

Comment: This question would possibly be better asked on https://security.stackexchange.com/